# Unable to decrypt p7m using MimeKit

Tags: c#, cryptography, smime, mimekit

I have located my `smime.p7m` from my email message, I read it as stream and try to decrypt it using MimeKit, but it failed with `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data)) {
    CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(WindowsSecureMimeContext));
    ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms);
    var ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    p7m.Verify(ctx, out MimeEntity output);
}
```

Following the example on https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit doesn't help either. Anyone familiar with MimeKit could chime in?

EDIT:

After decrypting the p7m, am I supposed to use the `MimeParser` to parse the content? I got the following from the decryption:

```
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m; smime-type=signed-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m

MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCAJIAEWUNvbnRl
bnQtVHlwZTogdGV4dC9wbGFpbjsNCgljaGFyc2V0PSJ1cy1hc2NpaSINCkNvbnRlbnQtVHJhbnNm
ZXItRW5jb2Rpbmc6IDdiaXQNCg0KdGVzdA0KAAAAAAAAoIImTTCCBaIwggOKoAMCAQICBguC3JQz
...more...
```

But when parsing with `MimeParser`,

```
System.FormatException: Failed to parse message headers.
   at MimeKit.MimeParser.ParseMessage(Byte* inbuf, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MimeKit.MimeParser.ParseMessage(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

UPDATE:

Ah, so it turns, calling `Decrypt` only gives me the `SignedData`, I need to then call Verify to pull the original data... this is kind of misleading, I thought `Verify` would simply verify it... which is why I didn't bother calling it, since I don't really need to verify it... Perhaps it should be call `Decode` instead? That's what I was trying to do originally, `((MimePart) signedData).Content.DecodeTo(...)`.

So in the end, I had to do something like this to extract the data.

```
CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(WindowsSecureMimeContext));
ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms);
var ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

if (p7m != null && p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData)
{
    // the top-level MIME part of the message is encrypted using S/MIME
    p7m = p7m.Decrypt() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
}


if (p7m != null && p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.SignedData)
{
    p7m.Verify(out MimeEntity original);    // THE REAL DECRYPTED DATA
    using (MemoryStream dump = new MemoryStream())
    {
        original.WriteTo(dump);
        decrypted = dump.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `data` contain? I'm betting it's not the correct content for this. Parse the message using `MimeMessage.Load()` and then find the `ApplicationPkcs7Mime` `BodyPart` to verify. Check the Unit Tests in MimeKit's github repo to see examples.

Comment: `data` was the p7m attachment that was first read as byte, then converted into `MemoryStream` in order for it to be converted into `ApplicationPkcs7Mime`.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting an InvalidOperationException because you are calling Verify() on a EncryptedData.

You need to call Decrypt().

Verify() is for SignedData.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I was trying various different things and originally did not had the code `CryptographyContext.Register`. After I added that line I didn't go back and try to `Decrypt` it.

Comment: Is it ok if I cast the output `MimeEntity` and just replace it with the `p7m`? Meaning `p7m = (ApplicationPkcs7Mime) p7m.Decrypt(ctx);`. Just so that I can call `Verify` on it?

Comment: If you know that the decrypted content is an ApplicationPkcs7Mime object, yes.

Comment: Am I supposed to use `MimeParser` to parse the decrypted content? I am getting `Failed to parse message headers.` See updated question.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Please add your code so I can see what you are doing.

Comment: Hi jstedfast, please see updated question. Also, is it possible to decrypt an UNSIGNED email? I tried calling `Decrypt` on the p7m that does not have the certificate/signature in it (the email was sent from Mac Mail client where they could encrypt without signing). Right now it is returning `null` when I try to decrypt that.

Comment: Verify() doesn't decrypt, it simply extracts the original content. There's no decryption.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking with regards to decrypting unsigned content. Huh!?!?!?

Comment: In Apple Mac Mail, you can send unsigned but encrypted email. Using MimeKit I was unable to Decrypt that.

Comment: Just call Decrypt() in that case, don’t call Verify(). You are making this WAY more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: I am calling Decrypt though, but is throwing `The enveloped-data message does not contain the specified recipient.`

Comment: That probably means that the message wasn't encrypted to any certificate for which you have the private key.